# Connecting GemFire using Spring Boot and Spring Data GemFire

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, gemfire, geode

I am trying to connect to an existing GemFire Locator using Spring Data GemFire and Spring Boot.

Following is my cache configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:gfe-data="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire   http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire/spring-data-gemfire.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<gfe-data:datasource subscription-enabled="true">
    <gfe-data:locator host="192.168.1.44" port="5555" />
</gfe-data:datasource>
<gfe:cq-listener-container id="cqueryListener">
    <gfe:listener ref="cqListener"
                  query="select * from /allSensors " />
</gfe:cq-listener-container>

<bean id="cqListener" class="cabigemfire.CQListener" />
</beans>
```

When I try to run this code I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ServerOperationException:  : While performing a remote execute     Functionorg.springframework.data.gemfire.support.ListRegionsOnServerFunction
at   com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.ExecuteFunctionOp$ExecuteFuncti onOpImpl.processResponse(ExecuteFunctionOp.java:623)
at     com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.processResponse(AbstractOp.java:218)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.attemptReadResponse( AbstractOp.java:153)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.AbstractOp.attempt(AbstractOp.java:372)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.ConnectionImpl.execute(ConnectionImpl.java:267)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.pooling.PooledConnection.execute(PooledConnection.java:320)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.executeWithPossibleReAuthentication(OpExecutorImpl.java:942)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.executeOnServer(OpExecutorImpl.java:375)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.OpExecutorImpl.executeOn(OpExecutorImpl.java:339)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl.executeOn(PoolImpl.java:732)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.SingleHopOperationCallable.call(SingleHopOperationCallable.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.ListRegionsOnServerFunction
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at   com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer$DSObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InternalDataSerializer.java:3563)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:2966)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3210)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.util.BlobHelper.deserializeBlob(BlobHelper.java:110)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.util.BlobHelper.deserializeBlob(BlobHelper.java:77)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.CacheServerHelper.deserialize(CacheServerHelper.java:55)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Part.getObject(Part.java:233)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Part.getObject(Part.java:238)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Part.getStringOrObject(Part.java:243)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction66.cmdExecute(ExecuteFunction66.java:124)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.command.ExecuteFunction70.cmdExecute(ExecuteFunction70.java:51)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.execute(BaseCommand.java:182)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMsg(ServerConnection.java:789)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doOneMessage(ServerConnection.java:920)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1165)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl$1$1.run(AcceptorImpl.java:577)
... 1 more
```

My POM is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>in.demi</groupId>
<artifactId>GemFireDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>continousQueryClient</name>
<description>A CQ client for GemFire. </description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>cabigemfire.ContinousQueryClientApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-gemfire</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>gemfire-repository</id>
        <name>Gemfire Repository</name>
        <url>http://dist.gemstone.com/maven/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

The main application is as follows:
    @SpringBootApplication
public class ContinousQueryClientApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("client/cache-config.xml");
    SpringApplication.run(ContinousQueryClientApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

What is the cause and how can it be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

So, this problem generally occurs when users start their GemFire Servers using Gfsh (with no Spring in the mix) and then subsequently try to connect to those GemFire Servers using a Spring-configured cache client, specifically with the `<gfe:data-source>` element, which incorrectly assumes the GemFire Servers were configured and bootstrapped with Spring as well.

I have separated the necessary SDG-provided `org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.ListRegionsOnServerFunction` class into a separate [JAR file](https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/22902/listRegionsOnServerFunction.jar) that can be added to a non-Spring configured/booted GemFire Server's CLASSPATH on start, or more conveniently with Gfsh's 'deploy' command.  More details on the 'deploy' command are available [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#deploying/topics/deploying_application_jars.html).

For more details on the issue, see... https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-409

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to create a JIRA issue for this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF. Meanwhile, try replacing gfe:datasource with gfe:client-cache and pool with subscriptions enabled. This will avoid calling ListRegionsOnServerFunction. Note that gfe:datasource is provided as a convenience and creates a client connection and a client region for each region discovered on the server via the remote function in question. CQ does not require a client region, so datasource is doing unnecessary work in this case, unless your application specifically requires a client region.