# java connection refused error with spring boot data geode remote locator

Tags: geode, spring-data-gemfire

Per my question [Apache Geode Web framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160334/apache-geode-web-framework) I've checked through various spring guides from [here](https://spring.io/guides) and spring data geode samples from [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/23/spring-boot-for-apache-geode-pivotal-gemfire-1-1-0-release-1-2-0-m1-released) and written a short spring data geode application but it cannot connect to the remote GFSH started Geode locator. The Application class is:

```
package cm;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClientCacheApplication;
import org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ClientCacheApplication.Locator;
import org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.EnablePdx;
import org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.config.EnableGemfireRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "CmWeb", locators = @Locator, subscriptionEnabled = true)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses= {CmRequest.class})
@EnablePdx
public class CmWeb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CmWeb.class, args);
    }
}
```

and in the resources directory `application.properties` I've set up the remote locator:

```
# Configure the client's connection Pool to the servers in the cluster
spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators=1.2.3.4[10334]
```

Build and run the application and it discovers the locator (which it returns as the server name)

```
[Timer-DEFAULT-2] o.a.g.c.c.i.AutoConnectionSourceImpl : AutoConnectionSource discovered new locators [UAT:10334]
```

A couple of seconds later it throws the error:

```
[Timer-DEFAULT-2] o.a.g.c.c.i.AutoConnectionSourceImpl : locator UAT:10334 is not running.
```

and

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.net.SocketCreator.connect(SocketCreator.java:958) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.net.SocketCreator.connect(SocketCreator.java:899) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.net.SocketCreator.connect(SocketCreator.java:888) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpClient.getServerVersion(TcpClient.java:290) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpClient.requestToServer(TcpClient.java:184) ~[geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AutoConnectionSourceImpl.queryOneLocatorUsingConnection(AutoConnectionSourceImpl.java:209) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AutoConnectionSourceImpl.queryOneLocator(AutoConnectionSourceImpl.java:199) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AutoConnectionSourceImpl.queryLocators(AutoConnectionSourceImpl.java:287) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.AutoConnectionSourceImpl$UpdateLocatorListTask.run2(AutoConnectionSourceImpl.java:500) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl$PoolTask.run(PoolImpl.java:1371) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.geode.internal.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorWithKeepAlive$DelegatingScheduledFuture.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorWithKeepAlive.java:276) [geode-core-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

After a lot of investigation I thought it was that the spring data geode client expects a spring boot geode server according to [Connecting GemFire using Spring Boot and Spring Data GemFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965092/connecting-gemfire-using-spring-boot-and-spring-data-gemfire) and so I downloaded the ListRegionsOnServerFunction jar and deployed it on the GFSH server get the same result (have not yet restarted the server...) but that causes the same error condition.

If by [Spring-Data-Gemfire - Unable to contact a Locator service. Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910285/spring-data-gemfire-unable-to-contact-a-locator-service-operation-either-time?rq=1) I try and change the application.properties from

```
spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators=1.2.3.4[10334]
```

to

```
spring.gemfire.locators=1.2.3.4[10334]
```

or other variations then the app can't find the remote locator and throws:

```
[Timer-DEFAULT-3] o.a.g.c.c.i.AutoConnectionSourceImpl : locator localhost/127.0.0.1:10334 is not running.
```

Writing this question I've finally found [How to connect a remote-locator in Geode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337443/how-to-connect-a-remote-locator-in-geode) and also can't PING the GFSH server from the SPRING app. However, the server bind address is setup properly for remote locator clients and various other services and UI using a locally built Geode Native Client for Geode v 1.10 can connect. I suspect PING may be disabled across this (semi-internal) network by default. I also disabled the firewall rules for ports 10334, 1099, 40404 to allow all traffic but still get the same error condition.

It turns out that from repeated INFO messages in the Spring Boot app *after* the connection refused:

```
[Timer-DEFAULT-2] o.a.g.c.c.i.AutoConnectionSourceImpl : updateLocatorInLocatorList changing locator list: loc form: LocatorAddress [socketInetAddress=UAT:10334, hostname=UAT, isIpString=false] ,loc to: UAT:10334
[Timer-DEFAULT-2] o.a.g.c.c.i.AutoConnectionSourceImpl : updateLocatorInLocatorList locator list from:[UAT:10334, /1.2.3.4:10334] to: [LocatorAddress [socketInetAddress=UAT:10334, hostname=UAT, isIpString=false], LocatorAddress [socketInetAddress=/1.2.3.4:10334, hostname=1.2.3.4, isIpString=true]]
```

and then running `list clients` on the server, the connection from the Spring Boot app to the Geode server v 1.10 is in fact established. Arrrgh!

It means the locator logic is working but this doesn't explain why after the first connection there's a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1 quick note about your Spring Boot application class...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "CmWeb", locators = @Locator, subscriptionEnabled = true)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses= {CmRequest.class})
@EnablePdx
public class CmWeb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CmWeb.class, args);
    }
}
```

The following statements are true iff you are using *Spring Boot for Apache Geode* (or Pivotal GemFire), which is highly recommended.

When using SBDG (by declaring the correct `org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter` dependency on your application classpath), then you do not need to explicitly declare the `@ClientCacheApplication`, `@EnableGemfireRepositories` or the `@EnablePdx` annotations since SBDG auto-configures a `ClientCache` instance by default, auto-configures SD Repositories particularly when all entity classes are in the same package or sub-package as the Spring Boot app and SBDG auto-configures PDX by default, as well.

The `locator = @Locator` just specifies that the "DEFAULT" GemFire/Geode `Pool` when configured via the `ClientCacheFactory` should connect to the cluster via Locators, on `localhost` using the default Locator port, `10334`.  Therefore, this attribute is mostly useless and I would recommend the **new** `@EnableClusterAware` annotation from SBDG (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative-annotations-productivity-enableclusteraware)).

The other attributes can be configured via Spring Boot `application.properties`, like so:

```
spring.application.name=CmWeb
spring.data.gemfire.pool.subscription-enabled=true
```

> TIP: You can configure subscription on individually "named" `Pools`, even via properties, if you are using more than 1 `Pool` (of connections) in your application, perhaps to route different payloads based on workflows to different "grouped" servers in your cluster, etc.

You started to configure the "DEFAULT" `Pool` in application.properties already with...

```
# Configure the client's connection Pool to the servers in the cluster
spring.data.gemfire.pool.locators=1.2.3.4[10334]
```

Regarding...

> *After a lot of investigation I thought it was that the spring data geode client expects a spring boot geode server*

No, SDG does not expect the cluster (of servers) to be configured or bootstrapped with Spring at all.  Using Gfsh is perfectly valid.  For [instance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.2.x/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html#spring-geode-samples-getting-started-run-app-clientserver).  If the `ListRegionsOnServerFunction` is not available, SDG falls back to other means (provided by GemFire/Geode itself, which Gfsh knows and uses).

All the messages you are seeing in the Spring Boot app logs are coming from Geode itself, i.e. nothing to do with Spring. In a nutshell, and FWIW, SDG/SBDG is a facade around the Apache Geode (Pivotal GemFire) API and Java client driver.  SDG/SBDG is at the mercy of this client doing the right thing, which of course, is partially dependent on proper configuration. Still... I am really just thinking out loud now since I suspect you are already well aware of (or have discovered) all of this.

I would also say the Java client and Native Client are not exactly an apple to apple comparison either.  Meaning, if you developed a client using purely the Apache Geode (Pivotal GemFire) API without Spring, you'd have the exact same problem.

I have never seen a case where the first connection is establish but subsequent connections get a "Connection refused", o.O  #argh

Have you tried this same configuration/arrangement with older Geode versions, e.g. 1.9?

Sorry for your troubles.  I will think on this more.

Comment: Thanks, shall try reconfiguration with @EnableClusterAware going forward :)

Maybe a reconf will solve connection refused which may be to do with DNS issues?

`DEBUG [poolTimer-DEFAULT-2] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.AutoConnectionSourceImpl queryLocators: Sending query to locator LocatorAddress [socketInetAddress=UAT:10334, hostname=UAT, isIpString=false]: LocatorListRequest{group=null}
INFO  [poolTimer-DEFAULT-2] org.apach.geode.cache.clien.inter.AutoConnectionSourceImpl reportDeadLocator: locator UAT:10334 is not running.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: the queryLocators can't find the UAT:10334 address but it can find the 1.2.3.4:10334 address which is running fine...